NetTopologySuite Filter out in-memory collections based on distance
I have the following code in EF Core, it translates to proper SQL code which filters out the items.
How can I do this for an in-memory collection?
var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(4326);

var location = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(request.Longitude, request.Latitude));

query = query.Where(x => x.Location.Distance(location) <= request.RadiusInMeters);

Basically my location object is the center, and I want to find all listings that are close enough to this center location based on the radius, which is RadiusInMeters
Again, the above code works just fine when its EF Core entities and the query is executed against the database, but I like to do this for an in-memory collection that has nothing to do with EF Core
